# Do the armours change your strength?

Tags: halo-4

Does armour (Etc recruit and hazop and all that) increase defence or fire power or anything?

Answer (score 4):

No, armor has no in-game effect, it's purely visual. Armor Abilities and Specializations are how you customize your play-style.

Answer (score 0):

Armour does not change any stats whats so ever. The armor is designed to be cosmetic/to show off accomplishments (some of them have difficult challenges to unlock).

The only things that change stats are your "perks", armor abilities, and weapons. There is also one "passive" ability that you unlock from one of the specializations that effects game play and takes no slots.